# r API GET, PUT, DELTE apply in a loop

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, httr

In R, I'm calling an url that would send images via GET call with specific ID. Then using an updated base64 image information of respective image I push the update or DELETE as needed. However, I am currently doing this one group at a time. Counties in Texas

```
County State zip
Bacon, Texas 76301
Noodle, Texas 79536
Oatmeal, Texas 78605
Turkey, Texas 79261
Trout, Texas 75789
Sugar Land, Texas 77479
Salty, Texas 76567
Rice, Texas 75155


county <- "Bacon"
upated_df <- final_df %>%
  dplyr::filter(county == "Bacon") %>%
  dplyr::select(name, content, order, group, contentType)

#' API get call
#' store the header and conten information in header variable
header <- httr::add_headers(
  "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", access_token, sep = " "),
  "Content-Type" = "application/json"
)

r <- httr::GET(
  url <- paste0(baseurl, "affiliation=",county, "&category=Images", collapse = ""),
  header,
  encode = "json",
  httr::verbose(info = T)
)

get_df <- httr::content(r, "text") %>%
  jsonlite::fromJSON() %>%
  tibble::tibble() %>%
  dplyr::select(id, content, hidden, name, contentType, description, order, group)

#' left join with the update df
ids_df <- get_df %>% dplyr::select(id, content, order, name, contentType)

final_upated_df <- dplyr::left_join(upated_df, ids_df, by = "name") %>%
  dplyr::select(id, name, content = content.x, order = order.x)

#' create a JSON format of the df
json_df <- final_upated_df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% # update each id
  dplyr::summarize(json_data = jsonlite::toJSON(
    list(
       name = name,
      order = order,
      content = content, #base64 converted image
      contentType = contentType
    ),
    auto_unbox = TRUE
  )) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(token = access_token)

#' function to call UPDATE

UpdateAPIcall <- function(df) {
  url <- paste0(update_baseurl, df$id, collapse = "")
  print(url)
  res <-
    httr::PUT(
      url = url,
      httr::add_headers(
        "Authorization" = paste0("Bearer", df$token, collapse = " "),
        "Content-Type" = "application/json"
      ),
      body = df$json_data,
      encode = "json",
      httr::verbose()
    )
}

#' run the API function on each id
    json_df %>%
          dplyr::mutate(grpid = id) %>%
          dplyr::group_by(grpid) %>%
          dplyr::group_map(~ UpdateAPIcall(df = .))
```

The above code runs one county at a time

- My final_df has updated information for each county. For example, if each county has 5 different images. I have 1 row per image ( base64 image), so if there are 3 counties the df has 15 rows.
- In the GET API call I get a data frame for that specific county entered.
- Further, I left join GET df to my updated df using the name field, to pull the relevant id from the get df.
- Then create a JSON structure with the updated values and the ID
- Finally, a PUT call to push update to each id.

This works 1 county at a time. However, my final_df has multiple counties that needs to be updated. How can I apply this across all counties in an efficient way ? I cannot share the APIs as it is not public and moreover the image information as well. Hence, just shared the county df.

Comment: Why don't you wrap all of this in a function and call `purrr::walk(unique(final_df$county), ~my_function(.x))` ? The ultimate solution would be to do this in a large `group_by(county) %>% group_walk(~...)` but your algorithm is so complex that it would probably get messy and unreadable.

Comment: @DanChaltiel, will try that. But, you mentioned that the algorithm is complex, can you let me know which one needs to be addressed. Is there a simpler way you can suggest ? Since, I need the ids to update or delete, I cannot avoid GET call, and then POST to create later